# Will Excel VBA calls to Internet Explorer work in Windows 11?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, windows-11

I read that support for IE-11 ceases in Windows 11.  I have report-creation code in some Excel VBA projects that call the objIE object (which opens IE).  Will those still work, or do I need to revise code?

Once I have created the necessary text in sHTML, THIS is called.  What is likely to happen in Windows 11?

```
Private Sub showReport()
Dim objIE           As Object
Dim i               As Long
    Err.Clear
    sReportPath = CreateFolder(ActiveWorkbook.Path, "Reports")

    On Error GoTo Error_Handler
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With objIE
        .navigate "about:blank"
        Do While .Busy: DoEvents: Loop
        Do While .ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
        .Document.Write sHTML
        On Error Resume Next
        If (tRptOpt And RptOptPreview) Then
            .Visible = True
        End If
    End With

    Set objIE = Nothing
    sReportFilename = vbNullString
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 11 will Support Internet Explorer 11 in its "IE Mode",
where almost all IE features will be available.

This includes:

> - All document modes and enterprise modes
> - ActiveX controls (such as Java or Silverlight). Note: Silverlight reaches end of support on October 12, 2021.
> - Browser Helper Objects
> - Internet Explorer settings and group policies that affect security zone settings and Protected Mode
> - F12 developer tools for IE, when launched with IEChooser
> - Microsoft Edge extensions (Extensions that interact with the IE page content directly are not supported.)

For more information see:

- [Internet Explorer 11 desktop app retirement FAQ](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/internet-explorer-11-desktop-app-retirement-faq/ba-p/2366549)
- [What is Internet Explorer (IE) mode?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode)

Comment: Thank You.  Answered my query well.

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer is mostly gone in Windows 10 (> 95%) and completely gone in Windows 11 (two Windows 11 Pro machines here).

So you need to re-write the code to use Chromium Edge and eliminate all dependence on IE.

Here is a reasonable support article.

[IE 11 gone from Windows 11](https://www.theverge.com/2021/6/25/22550714/microsoft-windows-11-internet-explorer-disabled)

> Microsoft revealed yesterday that Internet Explorer will be “disabled”
> in Windows 11. At first, I was worried that it meant Internet Explorer
> might hang around ahead of the final nail in its coffin on June 15th,
> 2022, but it’s actually fully disappearing from Windows 11. “The
> Internet Explorer 11 desktop application will not be available on
> Windows 11. Microsoft Edge is the default browser for Windows 11,”
> explains a Microsoft spokesperson to The Verge. “The MSHTML engine
> exists as part of the Windows 11 operating system to power IE mode in
> Microsoft Edge.”

As the article notes, Chromium Edge will support most of the IE 11 requirements, but still best that you re-work your VBA to fully accommodate Edge.

Comment: I was wondering where I should eventually take the VBA call.  Is there a way to initiate MSEdge from Excel VBA, or do I need to take the other paradigm of writing it to a temporary file and then letting the file-association take over by running the temp-file?

Comment: @IanHicks Take a look at vba-Selenium.  There are webdrivers for Edge and Chrome (as well as other browsers).  I just started reprogramming a web scraping task that I do to a secure site, and it seems to be going well.

Comment: OK.  I (personally) want to look at this, so where do I get the Selenium ocx/dll, and what extra bits come with it?
Why this won't gel in my client's workplace is that There's a BLANKET RULE about installing onto the PCs.  Oddly, they allow Macros, and they're a good-ol' MickySoft site, so Word, Excel, Outlook,... are the tools that their poor staff get to use.
If it were not for that, then I would've put in a c# system that would've been easier and quicker and prettier.  There will (possibly) be Edge soon, but Chrome is (in general) verboten.